# Rails deploy to Heroku with Webpack gves errors so Heroku can't compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack

When my app is pushed to Heroku from GitHub I keep getting an error message from Heroku saying my deployment failed. I then look at the Heroku build log there are the 2 following warning messages: "       warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".

```
   warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0"."
```

Webpack was installed by Rails and I had nothing to do to set it up other than making the changes as listed in "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" book by Michael Hartl

Does anyone have any ideas on how to correct this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include more context from your build log. If in doubt, include all of it.

Comment: I don't think these warnings are your problem.  I get similar warnings each time I do a `yarn add` but it never causes an issue.